# What affects the driving of the truck directly?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I want to know the things or events that changes the performance of the truck (except the upgrades on the shop),  just a brief summary or even a small list.

One of those that I want to know is for example, if the rain speeds up the truck, or does it modifies the handling a little bit, like from the other driving games (e.g NFS series), and also another one is that if the different roads (the brown-colored, the gray highway, etc.) do also changes the acceleration or just cosmetics.

Comment: This is far from a complete answer, but I've only noticed wet roads to change handling a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Damaging the Truck can cause performance malfunctions. Of course, the elevation or angle the truck is driving at affects the speed a small amount. I've noticed that the newer-looking roads can be smoother, and therefore improve handling, acceleration, etc.

Comment: the stamina of the driver can cause your driver so sleep while driving and get you in some trouble (mine slept on the highway at 100 KM/H and get me some heavy dommage on the truck).